# Div with sprite-animation doesn't change properly during window.resize event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to imitate 3d-model rotation with a sprite sheet. I found a perfect example on Codepen, but it was not responsive.

What I tried to do is to write divs, containers and spritesize (in script) in `vw`, and then it is being checked in the `window.resize` event. It does work, but unfortunately not DURING window resize.

I put my snippet and three pictures in the post —

1. I opened website and everything is perfect - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDuGq.png)
2. I started to change the size of my browser window and as you can see something is wrong - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU3FQ.png)
3. Now I tried to "rotate" the "model" with resized window and all is fine again - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8GSI.png)

```js
var spriteslider = document.createElement('div');
var clientWidth = document.getElementById('spritetarget').clientWidth;

document.body.appendChild(spriteslider);

spriteslider.slider = document.getElementById('spriteslider');
spriteslider.sprite = document.getElementById('spritetarget');
spriteslider.spritesize = clientWidth;
spriteslider.spritecount = 20;
spriteslider.pixelsperincrement = 5;
spriteslider.multiplier = spriteslider.lastmultiplier = 0;

Draggable.create(spriteslider, {
  type: 'x',
  trigger: spriteslider.slider,
  bounds: {
    minX: 0,
    maxX: 0,
    minY: 0,
    maxY: 0
  },
  edgeResistance: 0,
  cursor: 'e-resize',
  onDrag: function() {
    if (this.isDragging) {
      var t = this.target;
      t.multiplier = Math.floor(this.x / t.pixelsperincrement) + t.lastmultiplier;
      // TweenLite.set(t.sprite, { backgroundPosition: (-t.multiplier * t.spritesize) + "px 0"});
      TweenLite.set(t.sprite, {
        backgroundPosition: (-t.multiplier * t.spritesize) + "px 0"
      });

    }
  },
  onDragEnd: function() {
    var t = this.target;
    t.lastmultiplier = t.multiplier % t.spritecount;
  }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  var clientWidth = document.getElementById('spritetarget').clientWidth;
  spriteslider.spritesize = clientWidth;
  TweenLite.set(t.sprite, {
    backgroundPosition: (-t.multiplier * t.spritesize) + "px 0"
  });
}, true);
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font: normal 12px sans-serif;
  background: #000000;
  color: #91E600;
}

.spriteslider {
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 60px;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background: #FCFEFC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#spritetarget {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29123/heart.png);
  /* horizontal spritesheet - image from http://preloaders.net */
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class='spriteslider' id='spriteslider'>
  <div id='spritetarget'></div>
</div>

<p>Drag the box left/right to control the sprite's position.</p>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/utils/Draggable.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're referencing `t` in the `window.resize` event handler, yet that variable has been defined in a different scope, and is not accessible from that location.

To fix this issue you can replace `t` in that function with the `spriteslider` variable, as that's what `t` is expected to contain. Try this:

```js
var spriteslider = document.createElement('div');
var clientWidth = document.getElementById('spritetarget').clientWidth;

document.body.appendChild(spriteslider);

spriteslider.slider = document.getElementById('spriteslider');
spriteslider.sprite = document.getElementById('spritetarget');
spriteslider.spritesize = clientWidth;
spriteslider.spritecount = 20;
spriteslider.pixelsperincrement = 5;
spriteslider.multiplier = spriteslider.lastmultiplier = 0;

Draggable.create(spriteslider, {
  type: 'x',
  trigger: spriteslider.slider,
  bounds: {
    minX: 0,
    maxX: 0,
    minY: 0,
    maxY: 0
  },
  edgeResistance: 0,
  cursor: 'e-resize',
  onDrag: function() {
    if (this.isDragging) {
      var t = this.target;
      t.multiplier = Math.floor(this.x / t.pixelsperincrement) + t.lastmultiplier;
      TweenLite.set(t.sprite, {
        backgroundPosition: (-t.multiplier * t.spritesize) + "px 0"
      });

    }
  },
  onDragEnd: function() {
    var t = this.target;
    t.lastmultiplier = t.multiplier % t.spritecount;
  }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  var clientWidth = document.getElementById('spritetarget').clientWidth;
  spriteslider.spritesize = clientWidth;
  TweenLite.set(spriteslider.sprite, {
    backgroundPosition: (-spriteslider.multiplier * spriteslider.spritesize) + "px 0"
  });
}, true);
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font: normal 12px sans-serif;
  background: #000000;
  color: #91E600;
}

.spriteslider {
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 60px;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background: #FCFEFC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#spritetarget {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29123/heart.png);
  /* horizontal spritesheet - image from http://preloaders.net */
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class='spriteslider' id='spriteslider'>
  <div id='spritetarget'></div>
</div>

<p>Drag the box left/right to control the sprite's position.</p>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/utils/Draggable.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: It works just perfect! Thank you so much! It's really appreciated!

Comment: No problem, glad to help